# Azure Data Factory - Export data to sub container/blob

Tags: azure

Hi I have an ADF that copies (exports Azure SQL data) CSV files to a blob. 
How can I direct the the files - the destination to a 'sub' container

I have blob Named 'SQLdata' , I want the files to be create in sub-container/blob called customers

- SQLdata/Customers

  SQLdata/Customers/Cust1.csv

  SQLdata/Customers/Cust2.csv

I have tried

```
 "destination": {
                            "fileName": "Customers//Cust1.csv"
```

What is wrong with the following?

```
   "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Export",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [
                            {
                                "name": "Source",
                                "value": "dbo.@{item().source.table}"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Destination",
                                "value": "@{item().destination.fileName}"
                            }
                        ],




 "parameters": {
            "cw_items": {
                "type": "Array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    {
                        "source": {
                            "table": "Cust1"
                        },
                        "destination": {
                            "fileName": "Cust1.csv"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "source": {
                            "table": "Cust2"
                        },
                        "destination": {
                            "fileName": "Cust2.csv"
                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same export and it works well, all the csv files is stored in `containerleon/csv`:

JSON code reference:

```
{
    "name": "CopyPipeline_fls",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach_fls",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.cw_items",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy_fls",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Source",
                                    "value": "dbo.@{item().source.table}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Destination",
                                    "value": "containerleon/csv/@{item().destination.fileName}"
                                }
                            ],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "SourceDataset_fls",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "cw_table": "@item().source.table"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DestinationDataset_fls",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "cw_fileName": "@item().destination.fileName"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "cw_items": {
                "type": "Array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    {
                        "source": {
                            "table": "test"
                        },
                        "destination": {
                            "fileName": "dbotest.csv"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "source": {
                            "table": "test3"
                        },
                        "destination": {
                            "fileName": "dbotest3.csv"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Storage preview:

[image]

Hope this helps.